# Is there any alternative to keyUp to check whether an input was filled?

Tags: javascript, elfinder

So I have this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($('#proofAttach-filemanager').val().length !=0){
            $('#download_now').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#download_now').attr('disabled', true);        
        }
    });
```

The field with id **proofAttach-filemanager** is filled up dynamically using elFinder every time I upload a file.

Since the  code above is only running every time the page loads, I don't know how to update the **download_now** button to enable dynamically every time the field is filled (and without keyUp)

**HTML Segment:**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">

<label>Attachment</label>
<input type="text" id="proofAttach-filemanager" name="proofAttach" value="" class="form-control" readonly="">

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..." style="margin-top: 3px;">
  <button type="button" data-inputid="proofAttach-filemanager" class="btn btn-default popup_selector">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Browse uploads</button>
  <button type="button" data-inputid="proofAttach-filemanager" id="download_now" class="btn btn-default download_now">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download</button>
    <button type="button" data-inputid="proofAttach-filemanager" class="btn btn-default clear_elfinder_picker">
    <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i> Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: post your html code segment too

Comment: Doesn't elFinder fires any event?

Comment: That Download button is custom built.

Comment: How about putting this method inside change event? `$('#proofAttach-filemanager').change(function(){ //code here });`

Comment: use onchange event of `#proofAttach-filemanager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing your logic inside the `change` event of that text box should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   toggleDownloadButtonAccess();

   $('#proofAttach-filemanager').change(toggleDownloadButtonAccess);

  function toggleDownloadButtonAccess(){

    var $btnDownload = $('#download_now');    
    if($('#proofAttach-filemanager').val().length !=0){
       $btnDownload.attr('disabled', false);
    }
    else
    {
       $btnDownload.attr('disabled', true);        
    }
   }


 });
```

Comment: Doesn't work for some reason. To check whether it worked (since the button comes up enabled) I switched the top if to true and the bottom else to false (to disable whenever the field's length is different than 0). However, nothing happens.. Weird.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the change event is not firing?

Comment: Ooh I think I got what you are looking for. Give me a minute, will update the code

Comment: Yeah, it's not firing. I'm going to have to put the check the field logic inside a function or something to not repeat myself, since I also need to check whether the field is empty when the page loads.

Comment: Doesn't work, but I think I'm starting to understand why. The **input** is disabled by default, how's it going to check for changes if javascript thinks it's *disabled*? I don't know how to get around that. Thank you for the effort, really appreciate it. **EDIT**: In fact, it's READONLY. **EDIT2** Even removing READONLY still doesn't work. Weird!

Comment: May be you should create a fiddle. Its late here now, will figure this out tom morning in case you dint get this resolved by that time

Comment: I made it kind of work with this https://gist.github.com/madd86/9e4bafc03cc4f4ba216b67e11850e52f However, since there can be multiple upload fields on a form, I need to think about how I can enable/disable each input field accordingly. I appreciate your help.